# Modify shape of NSTextField focus ring

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTextField with rounded corners generated by subclassing NSTextFieldCell and overriding

> (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView

With the following

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    controlView.layer.cornerRadius = cellFrame.size.height / 2;
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

This seems to work fine, however when the textfield is first responder the focus ring still appears as a rectangle shape. Is it possible modify the focus ring to correspond to the shape of the NSTextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have done this; however it has been a while so it may take a few edits :)

I believe you have 2 options:

1. You can set `focusRingType` to `NSFocusRingTypeNone` then after `[super drawInteriorWithFrame:]` you can draw your own focus ring using something like `[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:]`.
2. You can override a private method called (I think) `_drawFocusRingWithFrame`

either way you will be drawing the ring yourself, but that part is easy. If you desire the system focus ring color use `[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]` for the stroke color of your path.

On 10.7 or later there is a method called `drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame` on `NSCell`.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `- (void)drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:inView:` and draw your own in NSTextFieldCell

It should be pretty easy to do by creating a path with your view's frame and adding some corner radius. Remember to use `[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]` so it matches the user's selection color.